# Plotting latitude and longitude from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Hello been trying to do this all day!
I have created a map with Basemap and I am trying to plot all the latitude and longitude locations from the CSV file. Any ideas or tips? 
Here is an image of the csv file

```
def map_test():
    col_list = ["longitude", "latitude"]
    dataset = pd.read_csv('charge_point_registry.csv', usecols=col_list)
    latitudes = dataset.loc[:, 'latitude']
    longitudes = dataset.loc[:, 'longitude']
    # Creates a base map ready for attributes

    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))
    m = Basemap(projection='mill',
            # coordinates of a box to contain map of UK
            llcrnrlat=48.632909,
            llcrnrlon=-14.452873,
            urcrnrlon=3.136989,
            urcrnrlat=61.648162,
            # quality of map
            resolution='l')
   m.drawcoastlines()
   m.drawcounties()
   m.fillcontinents(color = "green")
   geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(longitudes, latitudes)]
   gdf = GeoDataFrame(dataset, geometry=geometry)
   gdf.plot(ax=m.plot(figsize=(20, 15)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)


# m.bluemarble()
  plt.show()
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib Basemap is deprecated in favor of Cartopy. Here is some code that will allow you to plot your UK Data.

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import pandas as pd

long_list = np.arange(-179.5, 180, 1)
lat_list = np.arange(-89.5, 90, 1)

value_dict = {'latitude':[51.0, 51.2, 53.4, 54.5],
              'longitude':[-1.1, -1.3, -0.2, -0.9]}

#replace this with your df
df = pd.DataFrame(value_dict)

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj), figsize=(16,16))
ax.set_extent([-10, 3, 48, 61], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

fig.canvas.draw()
fig.tight_layout()


ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='0.25')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, zorder=10)

ax.scatter(df['longitude'].values.tolist(), df['latitude'].values.tolist())

gl = ax.gridlines(crs=proj, draw_labels=False, alpha=1, linewidth=0.25)
gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator(long_list)
gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator(lat_list)

plt.show()
```

[image: England Map]

Comment: I added, fig.canvas.draw() fig.tight_layout() to my answer above. Try the updated code and let me know if that works or not.

Comment: No problem. If you could mark as accepted answer I'd appreciate it. :) Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: Can Cartopy read lat-lon points straight from the CSV (like geopandas) or do I need to write the points in a dict within the script? Thank you, @MatthewBorish